# ValueError: Neither the x nor y variable appears to be numeric

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

Currently trying to do a violin plot from the `seaborn` package. But always get the error mentioned.

> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

table = pd.read_excel("path to the file")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(14,5)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Squad','Age'])

df = df.explode('Squad')
df['Squad'] = df['Squad'].astype('float')

ax = sb.violinplot(data = df, x="Squad", y="Age")
plt.xticks(rotation=65)
plt.show()
```

Would appreciate if someone could help. Thanks.

Edit : Did a silly mistake. Didn't include table in df. But after including that, getting a new error. When I added the `.explode()`, got the error that it could not convert it from string to float.

> ValueError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric.

Code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

table = pd.read_excel("G:/Others/football analytics/ageepl.xlsx")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(14,5)

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns =['Squad','Age'])
ax = sb.violinplot(data = df, x="Squad", y="Age")

plt.xticks(rotation=65)

plt.show()
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "G:\Others\football analytics\python\age_violin.py", line 11, in <module>
    ax = sb.violinplot(data = df, x="Squad", y="Age")

  File "C:\Users\MAHE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 2384, in violinplot
    plotter = _ViolinPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,

  File "C:\Users\MAHE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 552, in __init__
    self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)

  File "C:\Users\MAHE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 155, in establish_variables
    orient = self.infer_orient(x, y, orient)

  File "C:\Users\MAHE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 354, in infer_orient
    raise ValueError(no_numeric)

ValueError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric.
```

Comment: Can you share the full error (with stack traceback)?

Comment: @Aziz updated, but with a new error now.

Comment: @JohanC after updating the dataframe, another error pops up.

Comment: Probably you still need to add `df['Squad'] = df['Squad'].astype('float')` and maybe the same for `'Age'`

Comment: @JohanC Did that, get an error saying cannot convert the string to float

Comment: Well, then you found the error: the `'Squad'` column doesn't contain all numbers. You should investigate what's in it, and maybe remove some bad rows.

Comment: @JohanC Yeah, `Squad` contains all characters. Any idea on how to proceed?